# Send data to 'view' without loading it

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Is this possible to send data to view without loading it?
I working on google maps library for codeigniter. I am having scenario of listing hotels on listing page and when user click map it load google map showing that address. I am calling function in controller using ajax. The problem is output have 2 types of data. One should be inserted in `head` of the page and other into `body` in specific `div.`

```
echo $map['html'];
echo $map['js'];
```

`html` should be inserted in `div` while 'js' in head. Both are the output by function and return into response to Ajax.

The `view` file from where ajax is calling, is already loaded by another function. How to handle this?

**View file (Ajax function)**

```
function showMap(id)
{
var detail_id = id.replace('map_','detail_desc_');
var hotel_id = id.replace('map_','');

$("#detail_map_"+hotel_id).html('loading');

$("#"+detail_id).slideDown('fast');

    var data = hotel_id;
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo base_url() . "hotels/getMap";?>',
        data:'id='+data,
        type:'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            //$("#detail_map_"+hotel_id).html(data);
        }//end success
    });//end ajax   
}
```

**Controller Function**

```
public function getMap()
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $map_config['directions'] = true;
    $map_config['center'] = 'G 11 Markaz, Islamabad Pakistan';
    // Initialize our map. Here you can also pass in additional parameters for customising the map (see below) 
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($map_config);


    // Set the marker parameters as an empty array. Especially important if we are using multiple markers
    $marker = array();
    // Specify an address or lat/long for where the marker should appear.
    $marker['position'] = 'G 11 Markaz, Islamabad Pakistan'; 
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    // placed where we want the map to appear.
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

    //print_r($data['map']);

    echo $data['map']['html'];

            echo $data['map']['js'];

            //these two echos are sent back in response to ajax function
}
```

Now I want to put `echo $data['map']['js'];` in `head` tags while the other in `body` inside `div`.

Comment: No. You're not able to do that as far as I know. If you mean without rendering then you can set third parameter to `TRUE` in `$this->load->view(,,TRUE)`.

Comment: You mean it will load the view but will not render it?

Comment: MahabGM is correct. The TRUE parameter will not display the view. You will have to use it in an expression $page_segment = $this->load->view(,,TRUE), then send $page_segment to another page L $data['segment1'] = $page_segment; $this->load->view('mainpage' $data); which will display mainpage which can use locally  $page_segment

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about putting this returned data in the view where you've called `getMap()` from then you can do this in your controller:

```
$json = array(
  'html' => $data['map']['html'],
  'js' => $data['map']['js']
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

And then use them in JavaScript callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'<?php echo base_url() . "hotels/getMap";?>',
    data:'id='+data,
    dataType: 'json',
    type:'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#yourdiv").html(data.js);
        $("#yourdiv").append(data.html);
    }//end success
});//end ajax
```

Look for changes that I've done. Since this was going to make problems, I recommend to put `data.js` in your `div` too because every time you load a map, it'll append those returned data again and again if it was in `head`. This way it'll first dump your `div` and then it puts `data.js` and `data.html` appended to it.

Comment: The problem is I have two types of data, which should be differentiate when it return to ajax.

Comment: @MShahzadKhan You mean you want to get different data from same view?

Comment: I have added code to my question. Please check it, you may undersatand my question now.